# If else statement within formula using search

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use if else statements within excel formula if I use search?
For just comparing a cell to a value, it is pretty straight forward, but not with search.

This is how I search if the there is a value in the cell:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AAA";L2)); "yes"; "no")
```

This would be the pseudo-code:

```
if (in cell L2 is BBB) {

 write "DONE!"

} else {

 if (in cell L2 is AAA) { // this is what my formula already does !
  write "yes"
 } else {
  write "no"
 }

}
```

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BBB";L2));"DONE!";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AAA";L2)); "yes"; "no"))`?

Comment: Get some ideas form [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php)

Comment: @simoco yet again you are correct, thank you so much! (please write it as an answer so I can accept it and other people can also see it in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you can use following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BBB";L2));"DONE!";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AAA";L2)); "yes"; "no"))
```